# I can not set upper case Samba shared file name in Samba

Tags: networking, server, samba, smb

I created shared files via Samba. For example, I have a folder named TEST and I wrote it as upper case. It appears as lower case on windows. I just tried making the leading letter capitalized and it worked, but when all letters are upper case, windows shows as lower case. How can I solve this problem?

I also tried settings such as Default case Perverse case, but I could not get any results.

Comment: I think this is a Windows Explorer issue not a samba issue. Please see the following: https://kb.synology.com/en-my/DSM/tutorial/shared_folder_names_with_uppercase_letters_displayed_as_lowercase_letters

Comment: Windows does not see or use any settings you have made from Ubuntu such as permissions.

Comment: I understand thank you for comments.